# Unexpected infinite loop (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, infinite

```
while(true)
{
    unsigned int option;
    cout<<"1 - Display the list\n";
    cout<<"2 - Add a game title to the list\n";
    cout<<"3 - Remove a game title from the list\n";
    cout<<"4 - Exit\n";
    cin>>option;

    if(option == 1)
    {
        if(gameTitles.empty())
        {
            cout<<"\nThere are no games to be displayed. Please try again after adding some games to the list.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            for(iter = gameTitles.begin(); iter != gameTitles.end(); ++iter)
            {
                cout<<*iter<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(option == 2)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter the game's title:\n";
        cin>>newGame;
        gameTitles.push_back("newGame");
    }
    else if(option == 3)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter a game to be removed:\n";
        cin>>removeGame;
        theIterator = find(gameTitles.begin(),gameTitles.end(),removeGame);
        theIterator = gameTitles.erase(theIterator);
    }
    else if(option == 4)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\nThe option is illegal. Please try again.\n";
    }
}
```

When I choose any 1, 3, 4 or illegal option, the loop brings me to the top and I have possibility to choose again. The problem arises when I am trying to use 2nd option. I just enter in an infinite loop. But I want to enter a game title and after it is added to my vector (I declared it earlier) and then have possibility to choose an option again.

Comment: Check the code behind `gameTitles.push_back("newGame")`

Comment: The code you showed us is not relevant to the problem. BTW what about `switch` statement?

Comment: If you want to enter the input name to the vector then you have to write `gameTitles.push_back(newGame)` (leave out the quotes).

Comment: thanks, I did not notice the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the type of `newGame` but I would guess that it is of type `std::string` and you enter a title with two words: the stream reads the first word and stops reading. The next thing you do is read an `int` which fails and leaves the value of `option` unchanged. From then on the stream won't do anything and just keeps reading.

The key error is not checking that the read attempt was successful before using the result: you **always** need to verify that your input was successful **after** reading and before using the result. When an input operation fails the stream goes into failure mode, i.e., `std::ios_base::failbit` gets set, and it converts to `false` instead of `true` (well, actually it converts to a null pointer vs. a non-null pointer but that's a detail irrelevant to this discussion). Once in failure state the stream won't do anything until the stream state is `clear()`ed. You you probably also need to `ignore()` the offending characters.

That is, you certainly should use something like

```
if (std::cin >> option) {
    // do something with the option
}
else {
    std::cout << "expected an integer: ignoring the line\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

To read the title you should probably read an entire line. Since the formatted input for the `option` will leave the newline character in the stream, you will first need to skip that character, though. That is, the input for the new title would look something like this:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, newGame)) {
    // ...
}
```

The `std::ws` manipulator skips all leading whitespace. That is probably OK for your needs. If the string being read can have leading whitespace characters something different will be needed.

Comment: Thank you. I typed the names with '_' instead of ' ' and it worked. Of course it is better to provide a possibility of entering any kind of space. But the goal for this program is to help me to learn vectors and iterators. So I am happy this far...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to cin again to the same variable `newgame`, put in a `cin.ignore()`. If I recall correctly, the first time you cin to a string (I'm assuming newgame is a string), it leaves a trailing `\n` so it will just automatically  enter through in later prompts.